# There is no valid default from email address configured for the domain

Tags: email, addresses, smtp

I have set Sendgrid up to send emails in Civi (smtp.sendgrid.net). I have set the from email address as my domain email address - john@johnsales.com.au. This is the same admin address set in WordPress. I have tried many different configurations. When I click Save and Send Test Email in Settings Outbound mail, I get "There is no valid default from email address configured for the domain. You can configure here ..." I have tried many things to rectify this but am not getting anywhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to setup your FROM email by going to the menu item **Administer > CiviMail > From Email addresses**

Address format should be like

"My organization" myemail@myorganisation.com

Comment: Thank you. I have it set up in this format: "John Sales" <john@johnsales.com.au>. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it says that it says that there is no valid from address is: You need to click the default option when you set up the from email address. I have done that and it now works. However, when I send a test email it is sending it to a domain that I mistyped. Hence it doesn't get delivered. I am trying to find out where the setting is for test emails.